# How to fetch the width and height of a programatically added view in Swift/ iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, view, height, width

I have added a UIView and a UIImageView programatically, but I need its width and height.
Is it possible to fetch it, if yes, please share how to fetch it.

Code:

```
let View1: UIView = {
            let viewView = UIView()
            viewView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            viewView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
            print(UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "backgroundColourSelected"))
            if UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "backgroundColourSelected") {
                viewView.backgroundColor = self.viewColor
            }else {
                viewView.backgroundColor = .white
            }
            viewView.clipsToBounds = true
            return viewView
        }()
    
        self.canvasView.addSubview(View1)
        
        View1.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: canvasView.centerXAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
        View1.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: canvasView.centerYAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
        View1.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: canvasView.widthAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
        View1.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: canvasView.widthAnchor, multiplier: aspectRatio).isActive = true
```

Comment: With that code, `View1` width will be equal to `canvasView` width, and `View1` height will be equal to `canvasView` height multiplied by `aspectRatio`.  So the questions are: Where in your code are you doing this? Where in your code are you trying to get the width and height? And, importantly, ***why*** are you trying to get the width and height?

Answer (score 0):

use override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() for ViewController and override func layoutSubviews() for UIView.

Example : -  for UIViewControllers

```
override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
    print(yourView.frame.height)
}
```

for UIViews

```
override func layoutSubviews() {
    print(yourView.frame.height)
    print(yourView.frame.width)

}
```

Since your view is inside the function just move it out

```
class YourController / YourView {
private let imgView: UIImageView = {
    let iv = UIImageView()
    // do whatever you want with your image using iv. eg. iv.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit or iv.image = UIImage(named: "custom_img")
    return iv
}()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    view.addSubview(imgView)
    //set constraints for your
}

// then use layoutSubViews(for views) / viewWillLayoutSubViews (for controller) and calculate the height
```

}

Comment: I tried using the above solution provided but didn't work. I have a UIView added inside a function that returns this view. There are constraints added for this view programatically. Could you please help me add the above code on a correct place inside my code. I have added my code above in my question. I need to get the final width and height of the view. @Rishabh Shukla

Comment: just take that view outside of that function .

Comment: I have edited my answer , check if it workout for you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to know the life cycle of view controller.

To get height of any view use `viewDidLayoutSubviews`.

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
      super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()

      print(view1.frame.size)
}
```

`size` property will print both final height and width.